# Is Sombra still invisible while being shielded by Zarya?

Tags: overwatch

Had a small arguing session with friends yesterday about this because I was being shot pretty much directly on while I was being shielded by my friendly Zarya.

Is Zarya's bubble turning invisible with Sombra ?

Does Sombra triggers out of her invisibility if shot while invisible and shielded ?

I'm worried a bit about trolls being able to mess Sombra's stealth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see at [about 2:24 in this video](https://youtu.be/jMGeG7NK9Xo?t=2m24s) that these players tested if when Sombra is invisible and protected by Zarya's bubble she turns visible.  It looks like **she does not turn visible.**
However, Zarya's bubble makes it pretty clear where she is.

As for if she turns visible when she is shot and protected, the only information I can really find about this is from a [battle.net](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20752005289) post.  They said:

> Zarya bubble does reveal allied stealthed Sombra, however as long as the barrier isn't broken her stealth isn't cancelled. Zarya gets charge as normal from this.

Contrary to what I found in the video, this user states it that Zarya's bubble does reveal Sombra if she is invisible.  I disagree about that point, unless they are referring to how the bubble reveals her position.  They do state that as long as the barrier of the bubble is not broken, then she will remain invisible.  I would imagine this to be true.  I would think that Sombra would in fact become visible if you shot her whether or not she was being protected.  It only makes sense for the game mechanic to work that way.

Comment: Maybe her stealth breaks if she takes damage, meaning being shielded prevents the stealth from breaking but reveal her location. I'll have to test this tonight.

Comment: Based on the video, Sombra's _position_ is revealed as long as the Zarya bubble is active.  This is effectively the same as removing the invisibility because enemies can follow the invisible Sombra and just shoot her when the bubble is gone.

Comment: Something's not making sense with your answer.  The video only tested situations when Sombra is invisible, yet your first paragraph (wrongly) says something completely orthogonal is false. The video also doesn't show Sombra being shot while invisible and bubbled.  What is clear, though, is that Sombra's position is revealed, _even if she herself isn't_.  That's just as important.

Comment: Does the edit help clarify? I don't actually play overwatch, I'm merely bringing forth what I found through my research.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in this topic http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20751545286, Zarya can shield Sombra but the shield will have a different effect when sombra is invisible.

Much like when mercy is healing or boosting Sombra, only mercy can see the heal, not the enemies. I'm guessing the same will happen to Zarya shield, only Zarya and Sombra will be able to see the shield.

Comment: This doesn't give me any information as of how the interaction works... Except speculation...

Comment: You didn't ask for information of how the interaction works, you asked if it triggers her out of invisibility or no. Don't downvote my answer just because I didn't answer something you didn't ask...

Comment: "Does Sombra triggers out of her invisibility if shot while invisible and shielded?", "Is Sombra still invisible while being shielded by Zarya?", "Is Zarya's bubble turning invisible with Sombra ?". None of the questions asked were answered by your "answer". You are guessing what is happenning.

Comment: Well, I can't enter in overwatch right now. Wouldn't it be much easier if you tested your theory in game? =/